# XML name with '*' causing problems with XPath

Tags: html, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to write XPath for use in Selenium tests in Robot framework.

The problem I am running into is that an identifier I want to use is called `id*`, and the `*` in there is causing problems.

The XPath I want to use is `//input[@type='text' and @id*='F_Date']`

When I try to run this test I get an error saying it is not a valid XPath expression.

Removing the `*` makes it valid XPath, but does not find the element. Unfortunately there is not a different identifier I can replace `id*` with.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `*` character is not allowed in XML attribute (or element) names:

> ```
> Attribute     ::= Name Eq AttValue
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
>                   [#x203F-#x2040]
> ```

Source: [W3C XML BNF for component names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar)

There is no "way around this."  Choose another character for the XML attribute name.  If you receive a document that uses `id*` as an attribute value name, the document is not XML; tell the owner to fix it or provide you with tools/libraries to process it because you cannot use XML tools/libraries because it's not XML.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE:- '*' character is not allowed in XML attribute or element Names.

Please try below code:

```
.//input[@type='text' and contains(@id,'F_Date')]
```